# Problemas al actualizar a Android Studio 3.6.2

Tags: android, oauth, build

Tras actualizar a Android Studio ha dejado de funcionarme la siguiente dependencia indicada en build.graddle

**implementation 'com.foursquare:foursquare-android-oauth:1.1.0'**

El error que me lanza al compilar es el siguientr

**Entry name 'res/drawable/notification_bg_low.xml' collided**

He optado por limpiar caché siguiendo las instrucciones de otras entradas de colisión similares, pero no me arroja mejora.

Sin dicha dependencia, compila bien

¿Alguna ayuda, por favor?

Comment: Una pregunta, estas usando Kotlin?

Comment: Buenos días. Así es.

Comment: La implementation, te la marca en amarillo y te sale que exista alguna actualizacion?

Answer (score 0):

Adiciona esto en las dependencias de tu build.gradle (app)

```
implementation ('com.foursquare:foursquare-android-oauth:1.1.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android'
}
```

Comment: Las respuestas que son básicamente código sin ninguna explicación se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir una descripción de lo que hace el código y cómo/por qué funciona. Lee [answer] y visita el [tour] para más información y recomendaciones.